# React and Firebase authentication system

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to use the authentication system in firebase.js.

I am receiving the following error:

> *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6*_.default.auth.onAuthStateChanged is not a function".

Here is my code:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASEURL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_IDenter code here
};

// Initialize Firebase
const fire= firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth();

export default fire;
```

Also, I have imported the firebase file everywhere, but I still cannot access the auth functions.

Comment: Where are you actually calling `onAuthStateChanged`?  I don't see that code here.  Please edit the question to be more complete.

Comment: My guess is that you're doing `auth.onAuthStateChanged( ... )` instead of `auth().onAuthStateChanged( ... )`.

Comment: Ok yes, it was the fact that i hadn't used parenthesis. Thanks a lot, and I'm sorry I didn't post my other file